# How to use LiveReload without rails, to serve html in the browser

Tags: ruby, web, livereload

I am working on the css and html of a simple web-project.

I would like to use [livereload](http://livereload.com/) to update what gets rendered in the browser on the fly whenever I make a change to any of the files in my project.

From the description on the livereload website:

> **What does LiveReload do?**
>
> LiveReload monitors changes in the file system. As soon as you save a
>   file, it is preprocessed as needed, and the browser is refreshed.
>
> Even cooler, when you change a CSS file or an image, the browser is
>   updated instantly without reloading the page.

Since this is not a rails/sinatra project, but just simple html/css/js, what could I use to get live reloading?

E.g. is there some lightweight server in the gem repos that could solve this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [catapult gem](https://github.com/maccman/catapult#catapult) to set up a simple sprockets app, without sinatra or rails. It is just a static site that makes it easy to use a sort of `asset pipeline`. I have used it a lot and I love it.

Then in your `Gemfile` you can add `gem 'guard-livereload'` project [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload#guardlivereload).

Just follow the setup instructions, you may also have to check out [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to get everything working nicely together.

I only am suggesting catapult because it makes setting up a simple static site incredibly easy with the added benefit of `sprockets`, `coffeescript` and your flavor of `sass`.

To do this without catapult, just run `bundle init` (assuming you have the bundler gem installed) in your root directory which will create a `Gemfile`. Then all you need to do is add the `guard-livereload` gem like I wrote above.

enjoy

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!
I did not know it was possible to use a Gemfile via bundle init, so that was the missing link.

Comment: I'm trying your solution and it does not work... I install catapult and create a new project. Then i create Guardfile by `guard init livereload` then i change its content so it can watch the right files. And then I run `catapult server` and open `http://localhost:9292` then when i change the file nothing happend. BTW, i do install the chrome extension.

Comment: @aisensiy You need to run `bundle exec guard` to make guard and livereload function. `catapult server` just watches your assets to see if they need to be compiled again while guard watches for changes and then executes whichever guard plugins you are using (look at your Guardfile to see the paths it watches). I believe running them both would also be fine.